# Getting error while running phonegap blackberry application second time

Tags: cordova, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-webworks

The following error has been occured while running phonegap blackberry app for second time in blackberry 10 simulator using Webworks SDK

```
[INFO]    Sending request: INSTALL_AND_LAUNCH
[INFO]    Action: Install and Launch
[INFO]    File size: 132655Info: Installing Project1.testDev_Project1___c8537c58...
[INFO]    Processing 132655 bytes
```

Also its displaying "unable to find result reply"

Please suggest me some answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be trying to remove the old version of the app first, and then re-deploying the new build.  Try manually removing the existing app from the simulator (click & hold on the icon) first and run your deploy command again.  Which version of the sim OS are you using (10.1 or 10.2)?

Answer (score 0):

I find this quite often when working with the Blackberry 10 simulator on VMWare, and I have found that freeing up host system memory by closing applications does help the issue. You can keep re-running the blackberry-deploy command multiple times until it works also, it seems to go away eventually.